# How can i write "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id_from_table1' and id='$id_from_table2'"?

Tags: sql

I have 2 sql tables called banks and sectors. When i click banks it shows bank campaigns and when i click on sectors it shows campaigns according to the sectors.

I want to display campaigns which when user selects bank and sector at the same time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just have one table called "campaigns" and then have a "type" column in there so you can differentiate the types of campaign? That would make this issue easier.

Comment: You should read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and act accordingly - it's very hard to write SQL queries about data and tables you cannot see - but without seeing any data or schema info I'd _guess_ that you maybe want a UNION query in the case where the user selects both options. Or you just need to run two queries from PHP and output both sets of results. As I say...hard to tell when no proper information is provided. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep two tables, use `UNION` to combine the results of two queries.

Comment: Side note: do not do SQL injection, paramtereize your queries properly.